# Incorrect multirow height

Tags: tables, multirow

I need to create a table representing hierarchical decisions, something like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | C | x |
|   | B +---+---+
|   |   | D | x |
| A +---+---+---+
|   |   | F | x |
|   | E +---+---+
|   |   | G | x |
+---+---+---+---+
|   | I | J | x |
|   +---+---+---+
| H |   | L | x |
|   | K +---+---+
|   |   | M | x |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Here's how I've coded it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} & C & x \\
\cline{3-4}
& & D & x \\
\cline{2-4}
& \multirow{2}{*}{E} & F & x \\
\cline{3-4}
& & G & x \\
\hline \\
\multirow{3}{*}{H} & I & J & x \\
\cline{2-4}
& \multirow{2}{*}{K} & L & x \\
\cline{3-4}
& & M & x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, LaTeX is consistently giving me this:

[image: Table with some vertical lines incomplete]

There seems to be a weird partial “extra row” between the horizontal line and the I, J row, but without full vertical lines. Any idea how I could get it to render correctly?

I'm on Windows 7, LaTeX version:

> MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4487 (1.40.12) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)

The same incorrect output is produced by running `pdflatex` and `latex`.

Comment: You don't need the `\\ ` after `\hline`.

Comment: @Thruston I can't believe it, *that was it.* I'm not familiar with the preferred procedure on this stack: should I just delete the Q as trivial, or would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I can acccept it?

Comment: Problems are only trivial once you know the answer, I'd let @Thruston answer it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `\\` is needed after an `\hline`.  So the mysterious extra row will disappear if you remove replace this

```
\hline \\
\multirow{3}{*}{H} & I & J & x \\
```

with

```
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{H} & I & J & x \\
```

The reason you see the "weird partial extra row" is (a little bit) interesting:  in a `tabular` environment, you can finish any row early by just putting `\\` and starting the next row.  LaTeX will complete the current cell, and then start again at the first column one row down.  Any "decorations", like vertical rules, will only be added to this current cell as it is finished. In your case the `\\` is enough to start a new cell in a new row that has to be immediately finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}[hvlines]
\Block{4-1}{A} & \Block{2-1}{B} & C & x \\
               &                & D & x \\
               & \Block{2-1}{E} & F & x \\
               &                & G & x \\
\Block{3-1}{H} & I              & J & x \\
               & \Block{2-1}{K} & L & x \\
               &                & M & x \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]